# Got error while trying to run localhost website on cPanel

Tags: php, path, connection-string

I have been trying to switch my web app from localhost to a school server but it's telling me it cannot find the path:

> Warning: require_once(/util/tags.php): failed to open stream: No such
> file or directory in
> /home/xiaoant/public_html/database_pizza/pizza/util/main.php on line
> 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/util/tags.php'
> (include_path='///') in
> /home/xiaoant/public_html/database_pizza/pizza/util/main.php on line
> 17

```html
    <?php
    // Start session to store user and cart data
    session_start();
    
    // Get the document root
    $doc_root = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    // Get the application path
    $uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $dirs = explode('/', $uri);
    $app_path = '/' . $dirs[1] . '/' . $dirs[2] . '/';
    
    // Set the include path
    set_include_path($doc_root . $app_path);
    
    // Get common code
    require_once('/util/tags.php');
    require_once('/model/database.php');
    
    // Define some common functions
    function display_db_error($error_message) {
        global $app_path;
        include 'errors/db_error.php';
        exit;
    }
    
    function display_error($error_message) {
        global $app_path;
        include 'errors/error.php';
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using window and hosted it on a linux server Please check you path if it contain upper case letters  directory names in linux is case sensitive unlike windows 
Also you could list all the files in directory to check

'''$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);
'''
And see if it there